# Route error in react app while using mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx, react-routing

I get a React route error immediately as I put in the code link to the Mobx store (`const len`). For example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

@inject('store') @observer class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const len = store.goods.length
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App is there</h1>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Done</legend>
          { len }
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I remove it (store.goods.lenght), it works, if it is there, I cannot reach any route. It exposes me the following error:

```
The above error occurred in the <App> component:
    in App (created by inject-App-with-store)
    in inject-App-with-store (created by Route)
    in Route (created by View)
    in Provider (created by View)
    in View
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
```

`<Provider/>` here is taken from mobx.

**UPDATE**

After I have added a decorator `@withRouter` before `App class` declaration, that error in the console disappeared. But this didn't solve the problem as for now it just cannot display the route, telling, for example:

```
Cannot GET /notes
```

Did anybody encounter such e case?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post what the "The above error occurred [...]" part is saying? But were I to guess, it could be that you are accessing store without having it declared in the component? To me, it looks like you should access it like this:

```
@inject('store') @observer class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const len = this.props.store.goods.length
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App is there</h1>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Done</legend>
          { len }
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Might be good to add some null/undefined checking in there too, unless you're absolutely guaranteeing that goods is part of the store.